How do I make the template reactive to changes in property attributes?
Consider this very basic calculator (try it here):
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-calc')
export class SimpleCalc extends LitElement {
  @property()
  value1 = 3
      
  @property()
  value2 = 0

  render() {
    return html`
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.value1}
          @change=${(e) => this.value1 = e.target.value}>
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.value2}
          @change=${(e) => this.value2 = e.target.value}>
        <p>Difference: ${this.value1 - this.value2}</p>`;
  }
}


It works as intended, the difference is updated whenever the value of either of the input changes. Now I would like to do the same thing, but with value1 and value2 not being "direct" properties of the LitElement, but rather attributes of a property, ie (try it here):
  @property()
  obj = {value1: 3, value2: 0}

  render() {
    return html`
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value1}
          @change=${(e) => this.obj.value1 = e.target.value}>
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value2}
          @change=${(e) => this.obj.value2 = e.target.value}>
        <p>Difference: ${this.obj.value1 - this.obj.value2}</p>`;
  }

But in this case, the difference is not updated "live". How do I make this work?

Reactivity in Lit is based on reference equality so mutating an object won't trigger an update as you've seen.
There are a couple ways to address this:
Manually call this.requestUpdate()
Doing so lets Lit know to re-render.
  @property()
  obj = {value1: 3, value2: 0}

  render() {
    return html`
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value1}
          @change=${(e) => {
            this.obj.value1 = e.target.value;
            this.requestUpdate();
          }}>
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value2}
          @change=${(e) => {
            this.obj.value2 = e.target.value;
            this.requestUpdate();
          }}>
        <p>Difference: ${this.obj.value1 - this.obj.value2}</p>`;
  }

Recreate the object so it has a new reference
This creates a new reference so that Lit can detect the property change and re-render.
  @property()
  obj = {value1: 3, value2: 0}

  render() {
    return html`
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value1}
          @change=${(e) => this.obj = {...this.obj, value1: e.target.value}}>
        <input type="number"
          .value=${this.obj.value2}
          @change=${(e) => this.obj = {...this.obj, value2: e.target.value}}>
        <p>Difference: ${this.obj.value1 - this.obj.value2}</p>`;
  }

A library such as immer can help with more complex objects.
Read more about it here: https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#mutating-properties
